# React Navigation v6: How to detect when screen comes into or out of focus?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

In React Navigation v4, you could wrap your component in `withNavigationFocus()` and then trigger a function using

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.isFocused && this.props.isFocused) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in React Navigation v6? All I've seen is that you can use `useIsFocused()` to detect if the screen is currently focused, but not to detect when it's just come into / out of focus.

Comment: Does this help https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen?

Answer (score 4):

Use [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) to run side-effects when a screen is focused.

> The useFocusEffect is analogous to React's useEffect hook. The only difference is that it only runs if the screen is currently focused.

```
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    // Do something when the screen is focused
    return () => {
      // Do something when the screen is unfocused
    };
  }, [])
);
```